# IndexError: line *** list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

I am using a raspberry pi 3, the programming language is Python and I am using Pygame zero and Thonny which is the same as Python shell.
Why is my error occurring?

```py
import time, random, math

WIDTH = 800 #window size
HEIGHT = 800

PLAYER_NAME = "me"
FRIEND1_NAME = "him1"
FRIEND2_NAME = "him2"

#PLAYER variables
current_room = 31 # start room = 31

top_left_x = 100
top_left_y = 150

DEMO_OBJECTS = [images.floor, images.pillar, images.superpellot, images.pellot, images.pac, images.goee]

TILE_SIZE = 50

player_y, player_x = 2, 5
game_over = False

PLAYER = {
    "left": [images.spacesuit_left, images.spacesuit_left_1,
             images.spacesuit_left_2, images.spacesuit_left_3,
             images.spacesuit_left_4
             ], 
    "right": [images.spacesuit_right, images.spacesuit_right_1,
              images.spacesuit_right_2, images.spacesuit_right_3,
              images.spacesuit_right_4
              ],
    "up": [images.spacesuit_back, images.spacesuit_back_1,
           images.spacesuit_back_2, images.spacesuit_back_3,
           images.spacesuit_back_4 
           ],
    "down": [images.spacesuit_front, images.spacesuit_front_1,
             images.spacesuit_front_2, images.spacesuit_front_3,
             images.spacesuit_front_4
             ]
    }

player_direction = "down"
player_frame = 0
player_image = PLAYER[player_direction][player_frame]
player_offset_x, player_offset_y = 0, 0

PLAYER_SHADOW = {
    "left": [images.spacesuit_left_shadow, images.spacesuit_left_1_shadow,
             images.spacesuit_left_2_shadow, images.spacesuit_left_3_shadow,
             images.spacesuit_left_3_shadow
             ],
    "right": [images.spacesuit_right_shadow, images.spacesuit_right_1_shadow,
              images.spacesuit_right_2_shadow,
              images.spacesuit_right_3_shadow, images.spacesuit_right_3_shadow
              ],
    "up": [images.spacesuit_back_shadow, images.spacesuit_back_1_shadow,
           images.spacesuit_back_2_shadow, images.spacesuit_back_3_shadow,
           images.spacesuit_back_3_shadow
           ],
    "down": [images.spacesuit_front_shadow, images.spacesuit_front_1_shadow,
             images.spacesuit_front_2_shadow, images.spacesuit_front_3_shadow,
             images.spacesuit_front_3_shadow
             ]
    }

player_image_shadow = PLAYER_SHADOW["down"][0]

PILLARS = [
    images.pillar, images.pillar_95, images.pillar_80,
    images.pillar_60, images.pillar_50
    ]

wall_transparency_frame = 0

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 155, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (128, 0, 0)

air, energy = 100, 100
suit_stitched, air_fixed = False, False
launch_frame = 0 

MAP_WIDTH = 5
MAP_HEIGHT = 10 
MAP_SIZE = MAP_WIDTH * MAP_HEIGHT

GAME_MAP = [ ["Room 0 - where unused objects are kept", 0, 0, False, False] ]

outdoor_rooms = range(1, 26)
for planetsectors in range(1, 26): #rooms 1 to 25 are generated here
    GAME_MAP.append( ["The dusty planet surface", 13, 13, True, True] )

GAME_MAP  += [
        #["Room name", height, width, Top exit?, Right exit?]
        ["The airlock", 10, 5, False, False], # room 26
        ["The engineering lab", 13, 13, False, False], # room 27
        ["Poodle Mission Control", 9, 13, False, True], # room 28
        ["The viewing gallery", 9, 15, False, False], # room 29
        ["The crew's bathroom", 5, 5, False, False], # room 30
        ["The airlock entry bay", 7, 11, True, True], # room 31
        ["Left elbow room", 9, 7, True, False], # room 32
        ["Right elbow room", 7, 13, True, True], # room 33
        ["The science lab", 13, 13, False, True], # room 34
        ["The greenhouse", 13, 13, True, False], # room 35
        [PLAYER_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, False, False], # room 36
        ["West corridor", 15, 5, True, True], # room 37
        ["The briefing room", 7, 13, False, True], # room 38
        ["The crew's community room", 11, 13, True, False], # room 39
        ["Main Mission Control", 14, 14, False, False], # room 40
        ["The sick bay", 12, 7, True, False], # room 41
        ["West corridor", 9, 7, True, False], # room 42
        ["Utilities control room", 9, 9, False, True], # room 43
        ["Systems engineering bay", 9, 11, False, False], # room 44
        ["Security portal to Mission Control", 7, 7, True, False], # room 45
        [FRIEND1_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, True, True], # room 46
        [FRIEND2_NAME + "'s sleeping quarters", 9, 11, True, True], # room 47
        ["The pipeworks", 13, 11, True, False], # room 48
        ["The chief scientist's office", 9, 7, True, True], # room 49
        ["The robot workshop", 9, 11, True, False] # room 50
        ]

#simple sanity check on map above to check data entry
assert len(GAME_MAP)-1 == MAP_SIZE, "Map size and GAME_MAP don't match"

objects = {
    0: [images.floor, None, "The floor is shiny and clean"],
    1: [images.pillar, images.full_shadow, "The wall is smooth and cold"],
}

items_player_may_carry = list(range(53, 82))
# Numbers below are for floor, pressure pad, soil, toxic floor.
items_player_may_stand_on = items_player_may_carry + [0, 39, 2, 48]

scenery = {
    26: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1,1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]],
    27: [[33,5,5], [33,1,1], [33,1,8], [47,5,2],
         [47,3,10], [47,9,8], [42,1,6]],
    28: [[27,0,3], [41,4,3], [41,4,7]],
    29: [[7,2,6], [6,2,8], [12,1,13], [44,0,1],
         [36,4,10], [10,1,1], [19,4,2], [17,4,4]],
    30: [[34,1,1], [35,1,3]],
    31: [[11,1,1], [19,1,8], [46,1,3]],
    32: [[48,2,2], [48,2,3], [48,2,4], [48,3,2], [48,3,3],
         [48,3,4], [48,4,2], [48,4,3], [48,4,4]],
    33: [[13,1,1], [13,1,3], [13,1,8], [13,1,10], [48,2,1],
         [48,2,7], [48,3,6], [48,3,3]],
    34: [[37,2,2], [32,6,7], [37,10,4], [28,5,3]],
    35: [[16,2,9], [16,2,2], [16,3,3], [16,3,8], [16,8,9], [16,8,2], [16,1,8],
         [16,1,3], [12,8,6], [12,9,4], [12,9,8],
         [15,4,6], [12,7,1], [12,7,11]],
    36: [[4,3,1], [9,1,7], [8,1,8], [8,1,9],
         [5,5,4], [6,5,7], [10,1,1], [12,1,2]],
    37: [[48,3,1], [48,3,2], [48,7,1], [48,5,2], [48,5,3],
         [48,7,2], [48,9,2], [48,9,3], [48,11,1], [48,11,2]],
    38: [[43,0,2], [6,2,2], [6,3,5], [6,4,7], [6,2,9], [45,1,10]],
    39: [[38,1,1], [7,3,4], [7,6,4], [5,3,6], [5,6,6],
         [6,3,9], [6,6,9], [45,1,11], [12,1,8], [12,1,4]], 
    40: [[41,5,3], [41,5,7], [41,9,3], [41,9,7],
         [13,1,1], [13,1,3], [42,1,12]],
    41: [[4,3,1], [10,3,5], [4,5,1], [10,5,5], [4,7,1],
         [10,7,5], [12,1,1], [12,1,5]],
    44: [[46,4,3], [46,4,5], [18,1,1], [19,1,3],
         [19,1,5], [52,4,7], [14,1,8]],
    45: [[48,2,1], [48,2,2], [48,3,3], [48,3,4], [48,1,4], [48,1,1]],
    46: [[10,1,1], [4,1,2], [8,1,7], [9,1,8], [8,1,9], [5,4,3], [7,3,2]],
    47: [[9,1,1], [9,1,2], [10,1,3], [12,1,7], [5,4,4], [6,4,7], [4,1,8]],
    48: [[17,4,1], [17,4,2], [17,4,3], [17,4,4], [17,4,5], [17,4,6], [17,4,7],
         [17,8,1], [17,8,2], [17,8,3], [17,8,4],
         [17,8,5], [17,8,6], [17,8,7], [14,1,1]],
    49: [[14,2,2], [14,2,4], [7,5,1], [5,5,3], [48,3,3], [48,3,4]], 
    50: [[45,4,8], [11,1,1], [13,1,8], [33,2,1], [46,4,6]] 
    }

checksum = 0
check_counter = 0
for key, room_scenery_list in scenery.items():
    for scenery_item_list in room_scenery_list:
        checksum += (scenery_item_list[0] * key
                     + scenery_item_list[1] * (key + 1) 
                     + scenery_item_list[2] * (key + 2))
        check_counter += 1
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: Can you give us the full error message? Also what is the images thing you are using in the demo_array?

Comment: second last one

Comment: IndexError list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calculating the checksum, you use `scenery_item_list[2] * (key + 2)`. That will get an error if `scenery_item_list` has less than 3 elements, and one of the items is just `[1, 1]`.

If it's correct that some of the items can have fewer elements, you shouldn't hard-code the indexes in that calculation. Change it to loop over the list.

```
for key, room_scenery_list in scenery.items():
    for scenery_item_list in room_scenery_list:
        checksum += sum(scenery_item_list[i] * (key + i) for i in range(len(scenery_item_list)))
        check_counter += 1
```

Comment: i don't want another number it will cause an error, saying the room height is too low and ill have to change it

Comment: def generate_map():
    global room_map, room_width, room_height, room_name, hazard_map
    global top_left_x, top_left_y, wall_transparency_frame
    room_data = GAME_MAP[current_room]
    room_name = room_data[0]
    room_height = room_data[1]
    room_width = room_data[2]
    if current_room in scenery:
        for this_scenery in scenery[current_room]: 
            scenery_number = this_scenery[0]

Comment: i have deleted some parts because i have max characters but they are nothing to do with the error

Comment: `scenery_item_list[2] * (key + 2)` requires a third number in `scenery_item_list`.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to calculate the checksum without hard-coding the list index.